# How to reset/show all elements after hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please take a look at this **([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hk4wg/2/))**. I want to use data attributes in the select box to get the class names and hide some unorder list items. But I'm struggling to find out how to use `show()` to reset the list and display all the items after being hidden. Can anyone show me how to make the first option as a reset option?

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".showhidelist").change(function() {
        var  selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
        selected = selected.data('hide');
        $("."+selected).hide();   
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<select class="showhidelist">
    <option data-hide="">Reset/Show All</option>
    <option data-hide="year">Hide Year</option>
    <option data-hide="month">Hide Month</option>
</select>

<ul id="list">
    <li class="year">2004</li>
    <li class="month">Feb</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Like this.. http://jsfiddle.net/UeCaS/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hiding the values you are not resetting the options to initial state. Use $('li').show(); to reset the li's to show and then perform the action based on selection.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".showhidelist").change(function() {
        var  selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
        $('li').show();
        selected = selected.data('hide');
        $("."+selected).hide();   
    });
});
```